# Extract Year from properties of features in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, date, raster, google-earth-engine, landsat

While batch downloading the rasters from GEE

I want to pass the year, which are there in the properties of feature

[image: rasters]

so that it can name the output dynamically instead of numeric ID's i.e. the name should be `Level_2_Monthly_NDVI_LANDSAT_September_2017` instead of `Level_2_Monthly_NDVI_LANDSAT_September_1`.

[image]

```
var colList = all_out_raster_tiles.toList(all_out_raster_tiles.size());
print("All tiles Collection List ", colList)
var n = colList.size().getInfo();
print("No of tiles in Collection", n)

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      
      var img = ee.Image(colList.get(i));
      var id = img.id().getInfo();
      var listOfImages = all_out_raster_tiles.toList(all_out_raster_tiles.size());
      var Tile = listOfImages.get(i);
      var allRasters = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Tile]);
      print("Raster no " + i, allRasters)
      //var year_name = ee.Number.parse(allRasters.get('year'));
      //print(year_name);

      batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(allRasters, "USAKA_LANDSAT8_NDVI", 
      {name: 'Level_2_Monthly_NDVI_LANDSAT_September_'+id,
      scale: 30,
      region: roi
      })
}
```

```
Raster no 2
ImageCollection (1 element)
type: ImageCollection
bands: []
features: List (1 element)
0: Image (1 band)
type: Image
bands: List (1 element)
0: "NDVI", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:4326
properties: Object (4 properties)
month: 9
system:index: 2
system:time_start: 1504224000000
year: 2017
```

How to do so?

Comment: Please do not crosspost a question to multiple Stack Exchange sites (https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/408296).

Comment: Okay @KevinReid, Its just sometimes suggestions comes from anywhere, so posted. Will keep in mind from now onwards.